How to fix a 'error mounting' in mongo deployment? (kubernetes)
I am trying to run mongo with ssl settings via kuber deployment based on the docker compose container. I am new to kuber, having compiled and launched the manifest, I received an error that I did not understand.
Error:
Error: failed to start container "mongo": Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/a225fea0c6f8924b8eb2b9494aa9b2d0c46679c31422b13b5f7d1b6cf9aee3ba/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6a7ea8f346afde2e62e92473e6a8dd65992d37756b843768f83a5a5c5671b7ec/merged/etc/resolv.conf: read-only file system: unknown
Back-off restarting failed container mongo in pod mongo-768c78668b-2v964_sn-dev(7aaef1fb-c453-4fe4-b85d-36cde36ae85b)
Docker compose container:  (It works great)
 mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_ca.pem:/etc/ssl/ca.pem
      - ./mongo.conf:/etc/mongo.conf
      - ./mongodb.pem:/etc/ssl/server.pem
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    command: mongod --config /etc/mongo.conf

Kuber deploy:
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:

  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mongo
      namespace: sn-dev
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongo
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: mongo
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mongo
              image: mongo
              command: ["mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongo.conf" ]
              ports:
                - containerPort: 27017
              volumeMounts:
                - name: mongo-admin-user
                  mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
                  readOnly: false
                - name: mongo-certs
                  mountPath: /etc/ssl/
                - name: mongo-config
                  mountPath: /etc/
                  readOnly: true
          volumes:
            - name: mongo-certs
              secret:
                secretName: mongo-tls-secret
            - name: mongo-admin-user
              secret:
                secretName: mongo-admin-user-secret
            - name: mongo-config
              secret:
                secretName: mongo-config-secret

Secrets:
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:

  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: mongo-admin-user-secret
      namespace: sn-dev
    immutable: true
    data:
      mongo-init.js: cHJpbnQoIlN0YXJ0ZWQgQWRkaW5nIHRoZSBVc2Vycy4iKTsKZGIgPSBkYi5nZXRTaWJsaW5nREIoIkNvbW1lbnRzIik7CmRiLmNyZWF0ZVVzZXIoewogICAgdXNlcjogIm1vbmdvIiwKICAgIHB3ZDogIjEyMyIsCiAgICByb2xlczogW3tyb2xlOiAicmVhZFdyaXRlIiwgZGI6ICJDb21tZW50cyJ9XSwKfSk7CmRiID0gZGIuZ2V0U2libGluZ0RCKCJTdGF0aXN0aWNzIik7CmRiLmNyZWF0ZVVzZXIoewogICAgdXNlcjogIm1vbmdvIiwKICAgIHB3ZDogIjEyMyIsCiAgICByb2xlczogW3tyb2xlOiAicmVhZFdyaXRlIiwgZGI6ICJTdGF0aXN0aWNzIn1dLAp9KTsKcHJpbnQoIkVuZCBBZGRpbmcgdGhlIFVzZXIgUm9sZXMuIik7

  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: mongo-tls-secret
      namespace: sn-dev
    data:
      ca.pem: 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
      server.pem: 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

  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: mongo-config-secret
      namespace: sn-dev
    immutable: true
    data:
      mongo.conf: bmV0OgogIHRsczoKICAgIG1vZGU6IHJlcXVpcmVUTFMKICAgIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlS2V5RmlsZTogL2V0Yy9zc2wvc2VydmVyLnBlbQogICAgQ0FGaWxlOiAvZXRjL3NzbC9jYS5wZW0KICAgIGFsbG93SW52YWxpZEhvc3RuYW1lczogdHJ1ZQogICAgZGlzYWJsZWRQcm90b2NvbHM6IG5vbmU=

I was hoping that I could launch
mongo deployment based on doceker compose

I was able to run it by changing the location of the mongo-config from /etc/ to /custom/
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:

  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mongo
      namespace: sn-dev
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongo
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: mongo
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mongo
              image: mongo
              command: ["mongod", "--config", "custom/mongo.conf" ]
              ports:
                - containerPort: 27017
              volumeMounts:
                - name: mongo-admin-user
                  mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
                - name: mongo-certs
                  mountPath: /etc/ssl/
                - name: mongo-config
                  mountPath: /custom/
          volumes:
            - name: mongo-certs
              secret:
                secretName: mongo-tls-secret
            - name: mongo-admin-user
              secret:
                secretName: mongo-admin-user-secret
            - name: mongo-config
              secret:
                secretName: mongo-config-secret


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
